# Should this Perl 6 CATCH block be able to change variables in the lexical scope?

Tags: exception, raku

I'm playing with resumable exceptions. In this example, I try to numify something that doesn't numify. I catch that and attempt to give the `$value` variable an appropirate value then resume execution:

```perl6
try {
    my $m = 'Hello';
    my $value;
    $value = +$m;
    put "Outside value is ｢{$value.^name}｣";
    CATCH {
        when X::Str::Numeric {
            put "｢$m｣ isn't a number!";
            put "Inside value is ｢{$value.^name}｣";
            $value = 0;
            put "Inside value is now ｢$value.｣";
            .resume;
            }
        default {
            put "Unhandled type ｢{.^name}｣";
            }
        }
    put "End of the block";
    }

put "Got to the end.";
```

The `CATCH` block can see the lexical scope it is in, a resuming picks up where it left off. I expected that I'd be able to change `$value` and have the rest of the block use that value, but outside of the `CATCH` the value becomes a Failure:

```perl6
｢Hello｣ isn't a number!
Inside value is ｢Any｣
Inside value is now ｢0.｣
Outside value is ｢Failure｣
End of the block
Got to the end.
```

What's up?

Comment: I suspect it's an order of evaluation effect: the exception seems to interrupt the `$value = +$m` statement, with the assignment only happening after the `CATCH` block has been executed, overwriting the 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of a `try` block, `use fatal` takes effect, to cause lazy exceptions returned from method or sub calls to throw immediately. Outside the lexical scope of a `try` block, note that:

```
my $value = +$m;
```

Would result in a `Failure` being assigned to `$value`. The `try` turns it into something more like:

```
my $value = force-failure(+$m);
```

Which you could imagine being defined as something like:

```
sub force-failure(Mu \f) { f.sink if f ~~ Failure; f }
```

(I'm hand-waving because the compiler spits out the code to do this inline and with a few optimizations).

In the case under consideration, the `.sink` triggers the exception to the thrown. The `CATCH` block runs. The `.resume` indicates that we do not wish to unwind the call stack as would normally happen with a `CATCH` block, so execution continues inside of `force-failure`, which then returns `f` - the `Failure`. This all happens prior to the assignment in the mainline code to `$value`; the `Failure` is therefore assigned, overwriting the value given by the `CATCH` block.

Unfortunately, you can't escape this with `//=` because that does the test before running the RHS (which is what we usually want it to do). However, it is possible to do:

```
my $numified = +$m;
my $value //= $numified;
```

Of course, this is all a bit of a contrived example, since the normal idiom would be to not have a `try` block at all, and to write it as:

```
my $value = +$m // 0;
```

Thus taking advantage of the `Failure`. In general, resumable exceptions need a good amount of care, because in many cases code will not be written expecting a resumption to take place. It turns out that the code generated for fatalizing a `Failure` is one such piece.

Comment: Is this stuff documented? I only find vague references.

Comment: Hopefully, when someone finds lacking or unclear documentation, that person creates an issue at https://github.com/perl6/doc , so at least that problem will be looked at and not fall through the cracks.

Comment: So far I haven't been shy about making doc issues, but I also want to do my  homework first. So, there's https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1274 and https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1275.